# SonarQube v8.4 API Documentation: Get all projects and specific metrics

Tags: api, sonarqube, postman

I currently am attempting to get data for an analysis of all SonarQube projects within my organization. Right now, I can make API calls to get data on an individual project level, but I am not aware of documentation for SonarQube's latest version which includes calls like these from version 4.3:

Version 4.3:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392180

ex:
GET http://nemo.sonarsource.org/api/resources?metrics=ncloc,coverage

Version 8.4
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/

For my purposes, I just need Code Coverage and Quality Gate (Pass/Fail) from Sonar's front-end "Projects" tab. Any help in finding the right call to get Code Coverage and/or Quality Gates for all projects at once in Version 8.4 would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand the question you asked. Please correct me if I am wrong, you want to get the Code Coverage and Quality Gate (Pass/Fail) for all the projects in Sonar at once using WebAPI ?

Comment: That is correct @souravatta

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?  I have been able to successfully make the API call in previous versions but I know SonarQube has been restricting a lot so people and forcing them to purchase the reporting.  That in itself is a hefty tag. I am not sure which version more restrictions have been placed but 7.4 was working for me with no issues.